# apache-camel - Reading a java constants in spring xml

Tags: apache-camel

Trying to read java constant in spring xml file.

In spring.xml file

```
<util:constant id="speed"
    static-field="<packageName>.<constantclassname>.<constantName>" />
```

and using the property placeholder to read it

```
 <bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceHolder" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="properties">
         <props>
           <prop key="testProperty">#{speed}</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
   </bean>
```

and in route printing the property

```
<route>
<from uri=""/>
<setProperty propertyname="test">
<simple>{{testProperty}}</simple>
</setProperty>
<log message="print ${property[test]"/>
</route>
```

and in Constants java class file have defined the constant like

```
public static final String <constantName> ="xxxx";
```

While running this i am getting

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "xxxx" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "xxxx" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]

Am not sure why this requires ObjectFactory.class.

Please help me in resolving this or is there any other way to read a java constant file in spring.xml

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way of reading Java constants direclty from your class.
You can use camel **simple language**.

```
<route>
<from uri=""/>
<setProperty propertyname="test">
    <simple>${type:<packageName>.<constantclassname>.<constantName>}</simple>
</setProperty>
<log message="print ${property[test]"/>
</route>
```